Rails (with turbo) render form in place - how to update element outside of form
I have a model with some boolean columns. I would like to edit these as checkboxes in a form with instant update every time a checkbox is clicked. I managed to do this with onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" on each checkbox and then rendering the form in the controller with render :edit, status: :ok so we stay on the form.
Now I want to show an example of what the model does on the page but (I think) since the example is not part of the model, the element doesn't get refreshed.
I used the logger to print out the value of the example and I see it changing in the logger output but I don't see it change on the page.
In the below examples I removed form error handling to make the code shorter.
view
<div><%= @sample_invoice_number_format %></div>
<%= render "form", invoice_number_format: @invoice_number_format %>

form partial
<%= form_with model: invoice_number_format do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :yyyy %>
    <%= form.check_box :yyyy, onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :yy %>
    <%= form.check_box :yy, onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :mm %>
    <%= form.check_box :mm, onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

controller
  def update
    if @invoice_number_format.update(invoice_number_format_params)
      sample_invoice_number_format # this updates @sample_invoice_number_format
      logger.warn(@sample_invoice_number_format) # this shows the changed value
      render :edit, status: :ok
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails

Thank you. This will come in handy to get a better understanding of turbo streams. For now the answer below works beautifully.

When you render, the page is not updated, you have to redirect on a successful from submission:
# render :edit, status: :ok
redirect_to edit_invoice_number_format_url(@invoice_number_format)

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission

You could also respond with a turbo stream and update specific part of the page:
<div id="invoice_format">
  <%= @sample_invoice_number_format %>
</div>

<%= render "form", invoice_number_format: @invoice_number_format %>

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @invoice_number_format.update(invoice_number_format_params)
      format.turbo_stream do
        sample_invoice_number_format
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("invoice_format", @sample_invoice_number_format)
      end
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end


Awesome, works perfectly. I went with rendering a turbo stream for now.
